# How do I pass a php variable to a .php include?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, include

I have a file, lets say it's index.php where the very beginning of the file has an include for "include.php".  In include.php I set a variable like this:

```
<?php $variable = "the value"; ?>
```

then further down the  in index.php I have another include, say "include2.php" that is included like this:

```
<?php include(get_template_directory_uri() . '/include2.php'); ?>
```

How can I call the "$variable" that I set in the first include, in "include2.php"?

The exact code that I am using is as follows:

The very first line of the index.php I have this line

```
<?php include('switcher.php'); ?>
```

Inside switcher.php I have this

```
<?php $GLOBALS["demo_color"] = "#fffffe"; ?>
```

If I use this in index.php, it works

```
<?php echo $GLOBALS["demo_color"]; ?>
```

However, If I use the following code to include another php file

```
<?php include(get_template_directory_uri() . '/demo_color.php'); ?>
```

then inside demo_color.php I have this code:

```
<?php echo "demo color:" . $GLOBALS["demo_color"]; ?>
```

The only thing it outputs is "demo color:"

*edited for code-formatting*

Comment: Can you comment on the output of `var_dump($GLOBALS)` both just prior to including demo_color.php and then again on the first line of that file? Either share the interesting parts, or see how they compare (is there actually *not* a "demo_color" key in the later??

Comment: Ok, there are a ton of variables but I did a var_dumb($GLOBALS) before the demo_color.php include in the index.php and then inside the include.  You can see where the one inside the include starts by searching for "var dump from inside demo_color.php"  http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/vertex/

Answer (score 3):

It simply *can* be used in include2.php, unless the inclusion of include.php happens inside of a different scope (i.e. inside a function call). [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

If you want to be completely explicit about the intention of using the variable across the app, use the $GLOBALS["variable"] version of it's name, which will *always* point to the variable called `variable` in the global scope.

**EDIT**: I conducted a test against php 5.3.10 to reconstruct this:

```
// index.php
<?php
include("define.php");
include("use.php");

// define.php
$foo = "bar";

// use.php
var_dump($foo);
```

This works exactly as expected, outputting string(3) "bar".

Comment: For some reason this isn't working.  I updated the original question with what i've tried.

Comment: As you can see in my edit, I tested the declare-in-one-include/use-in-another and it worked as expected. You may need to share more specific code to identify your issue.

Comment: Would this being in wordpress have anything to do with it?  I have added the exact code, even the define/use code and I can't get any output.  Could it have something to do with server settings or permissions?

Comment: -1 although you are correct I think you should have pointed out that this is bad practice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175594/how-do-i-pass-a-php-variable-to-a-php-include#comment14662301_11175727

Comment: Hey, I like that you +1 for when people point out best practice; but -1 for leaving it out? On a PHP question, no less? How do I know if this is a 100-line job or an MVC application?

Comment: Basically this is a style switcher for a wordpress demo.  Javascript in index.ph gets the value of the colorpicker input, when you click the link it links to the homepage + ?color=colorcode.  switcher.php then takes this query from the url and sets it as a variable.  Then demo_customcolor would need to use this variable to adjust the css.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?PHP
//index.php
$txt='hello world';
include('include.php');

<?PHP
//include.php
echo $txt; //will output hello world
```

So it does work. Though there seems to be a bigger issue since this is likely to be difficult to maintain in the future. Just putting a variable into global namespace and using it in different files is not a best practice.

To make the code more maintainable it might be an idea to use classes so you can attach the variables you need explicit instead of just using them. Because the code around is not showed it is not clear what is your exact need further but it will be likely the code can be put in classes, functions etc. If it is a template you could think about an explicit set() function to send the variable data to the templates and extract() it there.

edit:

In addition based on the information first set your error_reporting to E_ALL and set the display_errors to 1. So you get all errors since the information you placed in your updated question gives indications that a missing variable is used as a constant which should raise errors all over the place.

Comment: There is one detail left out of this which might be the crux. The file in which the variable is declared is still in scope when include.php is executed. A slightly more complicated test is in order, where the file in which the variable is declared goes out of scope (i.e. it is declared in one include, and used in a later include).

Comment: I don't fully get your message, as far as I see it: You only call index.php. The includes should be in a non web accessible folder, so they never get called from web anyway.

Comment: Right, not from web. When I say "out of scope", I mean that the file "finishes executing" and returns to the point in the code from which it was included. I wondered if at that point, any variables declared in the file would be destroyed; but I ran a test and that's not what happens.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that what the OP is trying to do is bad practice and suggesting an alternative. Too few people do that on SO.

Comment: "Would this being in wordpress have anything to do with it? I have added the exact code, even the define/use code and I can't get any output. Could it have something to do with server settings or permissions?" I noticed this point (that's why it's important to ask a full question with all relevant points. If you use Wordpress that is a framework. It has guidelines on how to implement custom made parts of code. Please review the Wordpress framework to see where you should implement this. It looks like templating settings which is likely part of the theme but more information on that is needed.

Comment: According to this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/passing-php-variable-between-template-files there is just no way to do this?  I can't use the wordpress options or custom fields for a demo that uses cookies.

Comment: What do you mean with that last part? "Demo that uses cookies". Please add to your original question: What are you exactly trying to do? You reduced the information to the specific issue in your question which is a great practice but in this case too much info is missing I'm afraid. Your example is about a color, please specify who set that color and how it should be used in the presentation. Based on that you might receive some good practices on how to solve this properly structured.